# android fast load image from url

Tags: android, image

i want load about 50 image into listview
this is my code for load image from url

```
class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public ImageDownloader(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return mIcon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

but image load slow.
and I try use Picasso library, but loading speed slow too
how a better solution to load lot of image from url faster.
sorry for my bad English
thank you for reading

Comment: If using Picasso or Glide does not help, then your connection or the server are probably at fault.

Comment: no, everything is ok. but I want to know how is faster load image from url. because I have about 50 image to load same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add this to your android manifest

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

i use this to load videos faster, and it works for me ;) Maybe it'll also work for you

Comment: then i should consider to use a splashscreen in which you're loading the images and when that's done, going further to your main application

Comment: can you explain me, how to do it , i just newer in java

Comment: for info, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 1):

you should try UrlImageViewHelper module , 
download the jar from https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper , 
add it to your android project . 
then a simple command 
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someImage);
                                            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imgView,your uri);
also works with list adapters when views are reused.